# What does a quoted letter "N" following a name mean?

Tags: puntuación, abreviaturas, letras, símbolos

[This article](http://www.milenio.com/policia/detienen_a_homicidas-actor_renato_lopez-pruebas_crimen_pasional-asesinato-milenio_0_863313671.html) identifies two men with a quoted "N" following their names. Why?

> Policías de investigación del Estado de México detuvieron a Mario Alberto **“N”** y José Pedro **“N”**, presuntos autores materiales del asesinato del actor Renato López.

Is it a middle initial? If so, why isn't it in the middle?

---

[Este artículo](http://www.milenio.com/policia/detienen_a_homicidas-actor_renato_lopez-pruebas_crimen_pasional-asesinato-milenio_0_863313671.html) identifica dos hombres usando un N en comillas. ¿Por qué?

> Policías de investigación del Estado de México detuvieron a Mario Alberto **“N”** y José Pedro **“N”**, presuntos autores materiales del asesinato del actor Renato López.

¿Es una inicial media? Así ¿por qué no es en medio del nombre?

Comment: La N entrecomillada reemplaza el/los apellido/s.  Mario, Alberto, José Pedro y Renato son nombres.  López es apellido.  Pero por alguna razón u otra — imagino que podría ser (a) por ignorarlo/s el periodista, (b) por no disponer de él/ellos la policía, o (c) por querer la policía que los nombres se mantengan en secreto por ser parte de una investigación, o (d) por ser lo normal en Méjico no identificar a los presuntos delincuentes hasta encontrarse culpables.  Imagino que es o (c) o (d)

Comment: @guifa Gracias. Aceptaré este si publica ud como una respuesta.

Comment: creo que sería mejor esperar algún mejicano comente, para poder decirnos cuál de las cuatro posibilidades es la correcta.  No leo lo suficiente de las noticias mejicanas para estar al tanto en esto =/

Comment: Es raro, otras noticias de ese periódico ponen los nombres como es lo habitual: Nombre + inicial del apellido, sin comillas. ¿Quizá no es el apellido real? Hay cuatro nombres distintos en ese artículo que llevan la "N".

Comment: He encontrado más noticias con nombres con la "N", hasta ahora todas de periódicos mexicanos y que hablan de detenidos vinculados al narcotráfico. ¿Solo se usa en México? ¿Es exclusivo para narcotraficantes?

Comment: @blonfu Los en este artículo no son narcotraficantes.

Comment: @FracturedRetina es verdad, casualidad los otros que he encontrado sí. Pues entonces supongo que es una forma de ocultar el apellido, ¿será el nombre falso también?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo he [preguntado en un Reddit de México](https://www.reddit.com/r/mexico/comments/5i3cxk/what_does_a_quoted_letter_n_following_a_name_mean/) y me han dado distintas respuestas, todas coincidentes en señalar que esa "N" equivale a "No Nombre" y es usada para indicar una inicial supuesta, no la real.

> It's used to refer legally to a person who's last name is unknown, or whose last name may not be revealed for legal reasons.
>   It's similar to "John Doe" in that sense, which in Spanish is "N. N." (Meaning "No Nombre")
>
> Because it denotes that that letter is a supposed name instead of a real one.
>
> Because it is some kind of pseudonym to preserve the identity of said person. It is "N" to emphasize the fact that it is not a real name. If it didn't have the quotes, it could mean that his/her last name actually starts with N.

Comment: Entonces ¿por qué "Mario Alberto" en lugar de solo "Mario"?

Comment: @FracturedRetina porque es el nombre completo de la persona. Con "N" indican un apellido cualquiera. Por tanto podrían hablar de _Roberto "N"_, _José Luis "N"_ o lo que sea. En definitiva, `<nombre completo> + "N"`.

Answer (score 4):

El Nuevo Sistema de Justicia Penal Acusatorio pide, para proteger su identidad y evitar la criminalización, que a los presuntos responsables de cometer algún delito se les sustituya el apellido por una "N"... Se volverá a utilizar su apellido una vez determinada su situación legal (culpable o inocente).

Comment: ¡Bienvenido, JL!  +1 de mi parte.  (La respuesta quedaría mejor aún si citaras una fuente.)

Answer (score 3):

Es debido a que prevalece el derecho a la presunción de inocencia.

La Comisión Interamericana de Derechos Humanos y la Suprema Corte de Justicia han coincidido en que el derecho a la presunción de inocencia abarca la difusión del rostro y el nombre del inculpado, es por eso que debe haber una distorsión y un alias.

"N" no tiene un significado: simplemente lo usan arbitrariamente y ya para proteger a los derechos de la persona.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of the presumption of innocence; one is innocent until proven otherwise. If the news paper were to release the real names of the individuals involved or a photo of their faces it would be incurring in a crime.

Besides, any evidence that is found later it can be discussed by lawyers arguing that it was found because of publicity of the defendants.

Comment: Still, why do they use `"N"` instead of a mere `N.`?

Comment: Or indeed, why not X which is the usual unknown?

Comment: @mdewey N is commonly used for *nome*, and even more traditionally you have *NN* for *sin nombre* from an old Latin expression

Comment: @guifa yes indeed. The same is used in our Book of Common Prayer but it now seems a bit archaic.